# C# Reading or Editing a windows registry value issue in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c#, registry

I'm new to C# and I wanted to make a program that changes some of the registry entries in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, to be more specific the windows version ( for compatibility reasons )
for this to work there are two places to change:
1- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
2- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

I managed to make a read and write to the 1st .. but whenever I'm trying to make a read or write to the 2nd one, it doesn't read. I'll attach the pictures of where the problem is:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfYGa.png) works fine

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3erlN.png) does not read or write

here is the code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    
    namespace Registry_Modifier_alpha
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
    
            static RegistryKey BaseFolderPath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
            static RegistryKey FolderPath2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
    
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
    
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox1.Text = BaseFolderPath.GetValue("CompositionEditionID").ToString();
                textBox2.Text = BaseFolderPath.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();
                textBox3.Text = BaseFolderPath.GetValue("EditionID").ToString();
                textBox4.Text = FolderPath2.GetValue("CompositionEditionID").ToString();
                textBox5.Text = FolderPath2.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();
                textBox6.Text = FolderPath2.GetValue("EditionID").ToString();
            }
    
            private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:mail@mail.com");
            }
    
            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                RegistryKey BaseFolderPath = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", true);
                BaseFolderPath.SetValue("ProductName", "Windows 10 Pro");
                BaseFolderPath.SetValue("CompositionEditionID", "Pro");
                BaseFolderPath.SetValue("EditionID", "Pro");
                BaseFolderPath.Close();
RegistryKey FolderPath2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", true);
                FolderPath2.SetValue("ProductName", "Windows 10 Pro");
                FolderPath2.SetValue("CompositionEditionID", "Pro");
                FolderPath2.SetValue("EditionID", "Pro");
                FolderPath2.Close();

    
    
            }
    
            private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void toolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void toolTip2_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it's not reading the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

thank you

Comment: You're running a 32-bit application, attempting to modify the 64-bit registry. You'll get automatically redirected into the equivalent node under `WOW6432Node` (that's what it's there for), so you'll be writing the version under `WOW6432Node` twice! Open the registry in 64-bit mode -- see `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey` and `RegistryView.Registry64`. In fact, you can use this to write the 32-bit key as well without using `WOW6432Node` -- just open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` once with a 64-bit view, and once with a 32-bit view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open BaseKey based on different registry view:

```
var registryView32 = RegistryView.Registry32;
var registryView64 = RegistryView.Registry64;

var key32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView32);
var key64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView64);

var folder32 = key32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
var folder64 = key64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
```

### Update:

Based on your comment, here is how you can add it to your code:

```
static RegistryKey BaseFolderPath;
static RegistryKey FolderPath2;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var registryView32 = RegistryView.Registry32;
    var registryView64 = RegistryView.Registry64;

    var key32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView32);
    var key64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView64);

    BaseFolderPath = key32.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
    FolderPath2 = key64.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that I don't know how to do it,
can you please specify where do I put each line? much appreciated.

Comment: thank you very much for helping, after adding your code, everything worked out very well.

Comment: Glad to hear that